# How to watch any changes in object animation svg

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, mutation

I need to watch changes with att object animation svg

```
        const windowData = { 
        container: document.getElementById('window-container'),
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        path: '/windows.json'
    };
    const windowAnim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(windowData);
    const window2 = windowAnim.isLoaded
    console.log(window2)
```

I need to write code with
if (window2 === true) {...}

but i don't understand how can i watch any changes in this parament isLoaded in svg animation
after start page window2 have false and don't changes after animation is loading

Comment: How is the svg being animated? What is the value of `bodymovin`?

Comment: @AlexGourlay bodymovin is libraruary to load svg animations

Comment: @AlexGourlay animation looks like that: AnimationItem {_cbs: Array(0), name: '', path: '/', isLoaded: false, currentFrame: 0, …} and in this have isLoaded true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Lottie documentation, there is an event named [data_ready](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web#events:%7E:text=data_ready%20(when%20all%20parts%20of%20the%20animation%20have%20been%20loaded)) that is fired when all parts of the animation have been loaded. This seems to be what you're looking for.

You would use it as so:

```
const windowAnim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(windowData);
windowAnim.addEventListener('data_ready', () => {
     /* Your code to run when loaded. */
});
```